# Meaning of "a glimpse of insight"

Tags: meaning, idioms

I understand the words *glimpse* and *insight*, but what is the meaning of the whole idiom *a glimpse of insight*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Glimpse* here means a short experience of something, while *insight* means an understanding of something.

> The film gives us a glimpse of insight into the lives of Martians

means the film helps us understand their lives better by a little bit, since the film is only a few hours long but their lives are years long. Perhaps we should not see it as an idiom but rather a concatenation of the two meanings.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard idiom. The author is either a non-native speaker or a native speaker using a slightly unusual phrase for deliberate (e.g. poetic) effect.

If you understand both words you'll probably be able to make sense of the author's (I assume) intended meaning: *an insight perceived briefly as if glimpsed*.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker so forming a complete meaning of a phrase is not always easy. Thanks, now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Glimpse is almost always used in a physical sense of seeing briefly. Insight is always mental understanding. Therefore, I'd say glimpse and insight don't go very well together in a phrase. In Jasper Loy's example the sentence

> the film gives us a glimpse of
>   insight into the lives of Martian

would probably be better off with just 'glimpse' (or just 'insight').

> The film gives us a glimpse into the
>   lives of Martians

or

> The film gives us (some) insights into
>   the lives of Martians

While we are at it, 'flash of insight' is more commonly used to describe sudden, unexpected understanding

Comment: Yep, that's what made me ask the question. I agree with you that these words don't go too well together but I also find it's a rather creative use of English language. Kinda synesthetic.

Comment: Yes, the phrase seems a little redundant...